# get selected path by javascript window.open

Tags: javascript

I am using `window.open(url, "Download", "width=100,height=100");` to open a file save/download dialog. Is there a way to know the path selected by the user to download the file?

Also, in Chrome, call to the function doesn't open the save file dialog, rather automatically downloads the file to the pre-configured location. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Each browser will do its own thing, you can't force the save file dialog.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that you have access to the filesystem on the computer of the user? That would defeat security and open a lot of attack vectors. Why do you need to know/want this?

Comment: What does the code look like?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you want to do, but I'm pretty much sure, the answer is "No, you can't!".

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to know the path selected by the user to download the file?

No. It's beyond the jurisdiction of JS.

> Call to the function doesn't open the save file dialog

Depends on the browser. Chrome doesn't have one.

Chrome downloads files directly, only warning if the file is potentially malicious. As for download location, Chrome downloads at the predetermined Downloads folder of the OS you are using. [It can be changed](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95574) but that's the user's preference. You can't control it and you won't know if it has been modified.

Comment: I need the download file path to open the downloaded file in the native viewer on end user's machine.Seems like I can't get the info about download location using javascript and would have to fallback to some applet.

Comment: @user2331184 seems like I misunderstood the question. No, you cannot know the path where the file was saved.